# LED lights become darker?

Tags: led, heat, heatsink, diy

I build myself a light with many small LEDs. They are quite powerful. I superglued ever LED board (the LEDs where in parts of 3 on a small circuit board) to an aluminium piece to dissipate the heat.

But I think they got darker after the first month of usage (approximately 6 h a day) and the are getting quite hot.

Is it possible that the LEDs are loosing their brightness because they can't dissipate the heat well enough through the superglue?

Comment: How are you driving those LED's? What power and current rating do they have?

Comment: Junk LEDs? Driven too hard? Do they have a brown spot in the middle of the phosphor? Superglue is not a good thermal conductor. How hot are the LEDs?

Comment: So the LEDs are from Samsung and are driven by one of those constant current sources for LEDs with 350mA. Indeed some have a darker touch to them in the middle. I wasn't able to measure the heat but I would guess around 60°C

Comment: the superglue isn't ideal, but it's not terrible either if kept thin; you probably need to lower the amount of power fed to the LEDs, even if you find better adhesive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible. Use a thermally conductive glue. It also helps to maximise the copper area connected to the LEDs to spread out the heat over a larger area - the copper will conduct the heat a lot better than the PCB material or the glue. Use a lot of vias to conduct it to the backside of the PCB where it is glued.

Also make sure, that you are driving the LEDs according to their specification - cheap circuits might make the problem worse the hotter the LED gets (thermal runaway).

Comment: Yes, I think that's the way. I used some high grade Samsung LEDs and a constant current source of 350mA. This should be good for my LEDs, so I think they are correctly supplied. I will look for a thermal glue.